# How to determine CarPlay connection programmatically?

Tags: ios, carplay

Just would like to know: is there any way to programmatically determine if an iPhone is connected (via USB or Bluetooth) to the CarPlay system? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got any solution for the same?
 I am also working on the same

Comment: Were you able to figure out?

Answer (score 1):

CarPlay navigation apps can use the `CPApplicationDelegate` to find out whether they're connected or not. CarPlay audio apps do not need to do that.

Comment: Can we use Apple Maps SDk or Google Maps SDK in CarPlay navigation app ??

Comment: Technically, there is nothing that prevents you from doing that. Whether Apple lets your app pass the review is another question. You will probably have to have a strong advantage over the builtin maps app to qualify.